# Import entire file as a Sass Mixin?

Tags: css, sass

In my application I am constantly writing having to adapt my HTML to match a stylesheet provided by a third party.  What I'd prefer to do is to have an "adapter" written in SCSS, which makes heavy use of `@extend` to adapt from the third party CSS to my HTML.  At first blush, this looks fairly simple (using Bootstrap as an example third party CSS):

```
@import 'bootstrap';

.app {
  & > .right-nav {
    @extend .col-sm-3;
  }
}
```

In this example, however, all of Bootstrap will be included.  It would be preferable to only include the definitions that are actually **used** by my adapter.  Something similarly to a `@mixin`, where the CSS is only output if used.

Is this possible, or is there a way to write a "plugin" to get me there?

Comment: I believe you would have to rewrite Bootstrap into mixins. You could also consider reducing Bootstrap by using the custom builder: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
Alternatively, a framework that does something similar to what you want is this one: http://neat.bourbon.io/

Comment: I have looked into just limiting the "built-in" CSS, but the problem comes from those third-party stylesheets.  This app has a requirement to match the design from some larger affiliates.  As a result, the affiliates send ~200kb of CSS that doesn't match the HTML at all.  I'd like to adapt that to our HTML, without all the bloat.